# Unexpected output when passing array as argument of a vectorized function

Tags: numpy

In the example code below

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    print(x)

x = np.array([[ 0.31432202,  7.94263361],
              [-0.5346868,   1.93901039],
              [-0.47571535,  4.17720033]])

np.vectorize(f)(x[0,:])
```

As output, I expected to get something like

```
[ 0.31432202  7.94263361]
```

Instead I get

```
0.31432202
0.31432202
7.94263361
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with it? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How much of the `np.vectorize` docs did you read?

```
In [129]: def f(x):
     ...:     print(x)
     ...: 
     ...: x = np.array([[ 0.31432202,  7.94263361],
     ...:               [-0.5346868,   1.93901039],
     ...:               [-0.47571535,  4.17720033]])
In [130]: f1=np.vectorize(f)
In [131]: f1(1)
1
1
Out[131]: array(None, dtype=object)
```

`f` gets called twice, once to determine the return dtype, and once for each element.  Try it with 3 elements:

```
In [132]: f1([1,2,3])
1
1
2
3
Out[132]: array([None, None, None], dtype=object)
```

Note that the return is an array with `None`.  That's because your `f` doesn't have a return statement.  It just does the print.

Why are you using `np.vectorize`?  It has a clear performance disclaimer.  It also talks about the return dtype and how it determines that.  It's not a high performance way of calling a function that just prints something.  It may be useful for running a function of several scalar values, and you want to take advantage of `numpy` broadcasting.

**Read the docs**.

Comment: Thank you! I've read the docs but it went unnoticed. Sorry if it was a stupid question... I don't intent using the function for printing the values (as it was just an example code) but for calculating a mathematical expression with the values in a row. Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: I have in the past recommended including a print to better see what `vectorize` is doing.  In this case it reveals the initial trial call.  Specifying an `otypes` gets rid of that.